# Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' I don't know why

Tags: swift

I can't seem to find the problem, My code is very simple and basic, yet, this error won't allow me to get past this simple stage. Would be great if I got some help on this, thanks.

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource

{
    @IBOutlet weak var messageTableView: UITableView!

    var messagesArray: [String] = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()     
        self.messageTableView.delegate = self
        self.messageTableView.dataSource = self



 //add some sample data so that we can see something (because the
 array is orginially empty)


        self.messagesArray.append("Test 1")
        self.messagesArray.append("Test 2")
        self.messagesArray.append("Test 3")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

     }

        func tableView(tableView : UITableView , cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

        {
            //create a table cell

            let cell = self.messageTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell") as UITableViewCell

            //Customize the cell
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.messagesArray[indexPath.row]

            //Return the cell

            return cell

        }

        func tableView( tableView: UITableView , numberOfRowsInSection section: Int ) 
                return messagesArray.count

        }
    }
```

Comment: Fix your question using "edit" link at the bottom. As for the issue, try to implement all of the *required* methods.

Comment: check the edit code your problem was that you had the some code placed into the didRecieveMemory

Answer (score 1):

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` are nested inside of `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

You need to move the second last closing bracket up to after the line:

```
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
```

Comment: Thanks, I was going to edit the code, then I realized the brackets didn't match and I wasn't sure how to proceed..